# Method does not exist, is not static, or does not return the expected search results

Tags: apex, sosl

Hi I'm doing the challenge for SOSL Queries and here is what I have accomplished so far.

```
public class ContactAndLeadSearch {
    public static List < List < SObject >> searchList(String toFind) {
        List < List < SObject >> result = [FIND: toFind IN ALL FIELDS
            RETURNING Contact(FirstName, LastName), Lead(FirstName, LastName)
        ];
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I check the challenge I get an error of

> Executing the 'searchContactsAndLeads' method failed. Either the method does not exist, is not static, or does not return the expected search results.

I am not sure what I'm missing with my fragment of code.

Comment: You have a method name of `searchList` and the error says a method name of `searchContactsAndLeads` is what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered by @KeithC here is the updated code:

```
public class ContactAndLeadSearch {
 public static List<List<SObject>> searchContactsAndLeads (String toFind) {
    List<List<SObject>> result = [FIND :toFind IN ALL FIELDS 
                        RETURNING Contact(FirstName,LastName), Lead(FirstName,LastName)];
    return result;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ContactAndLeadSearch {

public static List<List<SObject>> searchContactsAndLeads (String searchstr)
{
//we need to first search for any records with the string assigned to searchstr 
//Then from the above list, we need to filter out records having the searchstr in either the FirstName or LastName
    List<List<SObject>> result = [FIND :searchstr IN ALL FIELDS 
                    RETURNING Contact(FirstName,LastName where FirstName =:searchstr or LastName =:searchstr),
                              Lead(FirstName,LastName where FirstName =:searchstr or LastName =:searchstr)];
    return result;
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Please go through [answer] section to understand what is the best way to answer. You should always explain what is the issue with original question and how your answer fix that.